# MATLAB to Python code snippet

Tags: python, matlab

I have the following **MATLAB** code, and would like to rewrite it in Python:

```
mean_ssd = sum(sum((imSrc1 - imSrc2).^2))/numel(imSrc1);
```

What I did in **Python** is the following:

```
width, height = Image.open(open(im1)).size
number_of_pixels = width * height    
mean_ssd = sum[math.pow(sum[(imSrc1 - imSrc2)], 2)] / number_of_pixels
```

I'm however getting the following error in Python:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'instance' and 'instance'
```

How can I rewrite the MATLAB code in Python?

Thanks.

Comment: what are the `imSrc1` and `imSrc2` ?

Comment: check `type(imSrc1)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this, instead:

```
import numpy as np

width, height = np.shape(imSrc1)[1], np.shape(imSrc1)[0]
number_of_pixels = width * height    

mean_ssd = ((imSrc1 - imSrc2)**2).sum() / float(number_of_pixels)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I got the following error: raise AttributeError(name)
AttributeError: get

Comment: Could you check what is the type(imSrc1) ?

Comment: Sure, this is what I get: <type 'numpy.ndarray'>

Comment: You should verify if this two numpy.array have the same dimension. You can check it like this: print numpy.shape(imSrc1), numpy.shape(imSrc2)

Comment: I modified the answer above, try the new versione. if the arrays have the same dimension, it should work perfectly! please let me know